# xml to powerpoint "pptx" xsl transformation using python lxml

Tags: python, xslt, python-2.7, powerpoint, lxml

I have a `text.XML` file which consists all the text that is to be replaced into different slide(s).xml files generated from `"Microsoft pptx presentation"`. The text from the input file has to be replaced onto different files(normally pptx generated files appear as slide(number).xml). Normally I have worked with single `XML-XSLT-XML` transformation but not with multiple files. I want to do this with python. Could any1 give me some hint how could I go since I am out of ideas or any high level libraries used for this. Currently I am using lxml.

Comment: I think it's not a library problem. If you can do XML-XSLT-XML for single input and output, you have to provide different XSLT for different ouput or make the decision in XSLT itself to get different result. So if you can provide the XSLT, any library support XSLT can do that for you.

Comment: @Harry.Chen thansk for your comment. That true.

Comment: If any who faces the same problem in future..I have a solution..Write different xsl files for different slide types/files..Then call source xml file and then call the xsl file, do the transforamtion and overwrite the transformed result to the slide.xml file..Hope its useful!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Python **lxml** library works through **libxslt** library which supports [exml](http://www.exslt.org/) extensions.
If you want to have multiple output files from one XSLT pass, then [exsl:document](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/index.html) element is exactly what you want.

> The **exsl:document** element is used to create multiple result documents.